# How do I enable mysql connection compression in spring boot application?

Tags: mysql

I have a spring boot application that is connecting to a MySQL db (MySQL 8.0). Here is the connection configuration in my application.yml file

```
datasource:
    url: "jdbc:mysql://${DB_HOST}:${DB_PORT}/${DB_NAME}?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false"
    username: "${DB_USER}"
    password: "${DB_PASSWORD}"
    hikari:
      maximumPoolSize: ${DB_MAX_POOL_SIZE}
```

I would like to enable [compression](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/connection-compression-control.html) on this connection pool. How can I achieve that? Not been able to find any documentation on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connection parameter is `useCompression`. It is a boolean.

Refer to [MySQL Connector/J Networking Configuration Properties: `useCompression`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-connp-props-networking.html#cj-conn-prop_useCompression)